# Where in my stack can streams solve problems, replace parts and/or make it better?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highcharts

If I take a look at the stream library landscape i see a lot of nice stuff (like mapping/reducing streams) but I'm not sure how to use them effectively.

Say I already have an express app that serves static files and has some JSON REST handlers connecting to a MongoDB database server. I have a client heavy app that can display information in widgets and charts (think highcharts) with the user filtering, drilling down into information etc. I would like to move to using real-time updating of the interface, and this is the perfect little excuse to introduce node.js into the project, I think, however the data isn't really real-time so pushing new data to a lot of client's isn't what I'm trying to achieve (yet). I just want a fast experience.

I want to use browserify, which gives me access to the node.js streams api in the browser (and more..) and given the enormity of the data sets, processing is done server-side (by a backend API over JSONP).

I understand that most of the connections at some point are already expressed as streams, but I'm not sure where I could use streams elsewhere effectively to solve a problem;

1. Right now, when sliders/inputs are changed, spinning loaders appear in affected components until the new JSON has arrived and is parsed and ready to be shot into the chart/widget. Putting a Node.JS server in between, can streaming things instead of request/responding chunks of JSONPified number data speed up the interactivity of the application?
2. Say that I have some time series data. Can a stream be reused so that when I say I want to see only a subset of the data (by time), I can have the stream re-send it's data, filtering out the ones I don't care about?
3. Would streaming data to a (high)chart be a better user experience then using a for loop and an array?